# Creating sequence of events in ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am new to AS3 and Flash. I have a very simple question. I want to create a sequence of event for my enemies in a game I am working on. So when my enemy is hit, I want the death animations to be played and after the animation is complete I want to remove the enemy object from the stage. The death animation takes about 3 seconds, so after 3 seconds I want to remove the enemy Object.

```
So this are the set of events I want
  1. Enemy hit check
  2. if hit, play death animation
  3. wait for 3 seconds
  4. remove the Enemy object from the stage.
```

I have used the Unity engine extensively and they have coroutines which work quite well if you want to create a sequence at different time intervals.

How can we do something like that in Flash with AS3?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far? Your question is not "very simple" - it's actually a relatively complex chain of events.

Comment: Your best would be to fire an event when your animation completes and do the clear up of the enemy in the handler for that event. That way, if the animation duration changes, you don't need to update the timing. How are you planning on animating the enemy ship?

Comment: Need more context.  How are you playing the animation?  is it a timeline animation in flash pro?  A Sprite sheet?   Show the code where you enemy hit is handled, and elaborate on the nature of the death animation and then someone can give you a clear focused answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take your chain of events and make a slightly more detailed chain of events.

1. Enemy Hit Check
   The built-in Flash functions hitTestObject and hitTestPoint will serve you well if you're thinking relatively simple hit test checking.  If you're looking for complex hit test checking (something inside of something else, checking from within) I would highly recommend "Bit-map hit testing" which is slightly more complicated.  Luckily, there are a plethora of online tutorials that can help.
2. if hit, play the death animation
   If you're using a MovieClip, you can set a frame by frame animation.  After you've built your animation in, simply call .gotoAndPlay(f) on your clip to frame f where f is the starting frame of your death animation, in order to get the animation going.
3. Wait for 3 seconds.
   If your animation takes 3 seconds anyway, put a function call in the last frame of your death animation sequence that sends an event up the chain to your "main class."
4. Remove the Enemy Object from the stage.
   You can then go off of the event in step 3 to remove the enemy from the stage.

Let me know if you have any clarifications/additional questions and I'll do my best to help out.